# How to tell link.exe to use wmain as entry point. LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, windows, linker

I have a project that builds and links via visual studio, but not by our build system.

From what I can tell, tchar.h contains a macro to convert _tmain into wmain if UNICODE is defined. I have checked the preprocessor output and indeed the _tmain has been replaced by wmain. The file containing wmain then compiles just fine, but the linker complains that main is undefined.

LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup

Is wmain converted to main by another set of macros that I am not including properly (through lack of -D options etc), or is there a special flag for link.exe that specifies the entry point.

Thank you.

Manually specifying /entry:mainCRTStartup fixed it.

Edit:
I have just checked the main.obj file. wmain is definitely defined.

Comment: There is a flag that specifies the entry point /ENTRY - however __tmainCRTStartup is probably the entry point you want.  __tmainCRTStartup initializes the CRT then calls wmain.  Could you try running dumpbin on the object file that supposedly contains wmain, see if your tracing of the #defines proved correct?

Comment: I want to accept your comment, but i cant.

Comment: Its not possible to accept comments and I didn't think at the time my comment answered your question.  If you think it did I will post it as a response and you can accept the response.

Answer (score -1):

MSVC uses a peculiar runtime startup, which is what calls the expected entrypoint `wmain()`, `WinMain()`, etc.

There is absolutely nothing magical about those names.  If you do not have the MSVC startup source code, implement your own startup module to fulfill your needs:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    wchar_t **w_argv =  some_conversion_function (argc, argv);
    wchar_t **w_envp =  some_conversion_function (some_count_function (envp), envp);
    return wmain (argc, w_argv, w_envp);
}
```

where I leave the implementation of `some_conversion_function()` and `some_count_function()` to you.

Comment: So at what point then does the linker know to use wmain as the entry point?

Comment: @user364952:  Just link this module in with the rest of the application.  C and C++ platforms by everyone but Microsoft call `main()` by default.  And if `main` calls `wmain`, the problem is solved.

Comment: There is a difference. Im relying on the linker (MSVC or whatever it is, i don't know) to produce the code that can handle wide character input. Otherwise it is simply converted to a question mark.

Comment: @user364952:  I have read your comment four times, but I'm not sure I follow.  If using `link.exe` directly, you have pretty good control over what is included and not.  Linkers do not pull modules from libraries unless there is 1) an unresolved reference to a symbol and, 2) a library which satisfies the symbol reference.  If you are using the MSVisual tools IDE, there are linker option pages which control including and excluding various modules.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that extremely badly, partly because really I have no idea what msvc is doing. The linker does at some point though arrange the executable in some way such that the os knows where to start execution. At some point some code that translates between this __tmainCTRStartup and wmain must exist. I have no idea who generates the __tmainCTRStartup symbol.

Comment: Apparently, when the user uses Visual Studio to build the project, it works. That means the program correctly handles Unicode input via `wmain`. Somehow, Visual Studio either provides a function like the one in your answer, or it uses a different entry point that calls `wmain` directly. We shouldn't have to write our own conversion function like this. The user's own build system might be omitting some flag that tells the linker which entry point to use, or which set of CRT objects to include. It's a problem solved by changing the build configuration (somehow), not by writing more code.

Comment: @RobKennedy:  The first line of the question contains *not by our build system* which led me to conclude they were not using MSVC as the tool.  Since that is apparently not the case, then I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: You can't magically create the wide characters from char*, this is misleading solution.